# Converting JSON long to a date in Java via Jackson

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, java-time

I have a JSON Data Object class as follows:

```
    public class Plugins {
      
      private String id;
      private String name;
    
      @JsonProperty("created_at")
      private long createdAt; 
}
```

Where `createdAt` is the long timestamp of the creation date. I use this class to back up  a Jackson `ObjectMapper` object parsing JSON data from an external API call. I was wondering if it is possible to have Jackson convert `created_at` automatically to a readable date format and store in Java as a `String` or `Date` flavour?

Comment: In which form `created_at` is coming? Can you share a JSON-sample?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko simple long timestamp, like `"created_at": 1665148545`

Comment: These are seconds from epoch? To do you want to store date-time in UTC or adjusted for a particular timezone?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Yes in seconds from epoch, and in UTC

Comment: And maybe you're using Jackson with Spring? I'm asking because in this case, configuring `ObjectMapper` isn't very straightforward since you're not using it directly, but the framework utilizes it under the hood.

Comment: No Spring sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Custom Deserialiser in jackson**

You can achieve the date conversion from **long to String or Date** by using the **custom deserialiser**. This custom deserialiser will convert the long value from the json into the defined date format(either Date or String).

**Please Note:** Here, I have converted the epoch value into the String datatype. In case if Date datatype is needed, you can change the implementation of the `deserialize method` of `CustomDateSerializer` class accordingly.

*You need to use the below annotation to the fields on which custom deserialisation is required.*

**`@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)`**

**Please find the code below:**

**Plugins.java**

```
public class Plugins {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Plugins{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", createdAt='" + createdAt + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**CustomDateSerializer.java**

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public static String pattern = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss";

    public CustomDateSerializer() {
        this(StdDeserializer.class);
    }

    protected CustomDateSerializer(Class<?> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        return formatter.format(new Date(jsonParser.getLongValue()));//change the implementation of deserialise method if date format is needed.
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
     //For sample input json, here i have used Text Blocks feature available from JDK 15 to have the string in readable format.
        String json = """
                {
                "id":"1",
                "name":"test",
                "created_at":1665158083000
                }
                """;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Plugins test = mapper.readValue(json,Plugins.class);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Plugins{id='1', name='test', createdAt='07 Oct 2022 09:24:43'}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. Is there a way to force it to read seconds instead of milliseconds? Or is there some error I am overlooking here, as the input '1665144716' gives '20 Jan 1970 07:36:48' instead of 7th October 2022

Comment: I guess the ugly solution is to simply multiply the input by 1000 but is there something more elegant?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine You are right, actually i have taken the input in milliseconds from the json but we can do the same with seconds as well with the below implementation: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).format(Instant.ofEpochSecond(jsonParser.getLongValue()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());`

Answer (score 2):

> if it is possible to have Jackson convert `created_at` automatically to a readable date format and store in Java as a `String` or `Date` flavour?

`Date` is obsolete and discouraged to be used.

Since Java 8 (which was released about 10 years ago) we have modern Time API which includes `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` and other classes from the `java.time` package.

You can change your POJO to make it store date-time information properly **without** the need to change the JSON payload. I.e. `created_at` can be received as a `long` value like `1665148545` and translated into `ZonedDateTime` (or other date-time representations like `Istant`, `LocalDateTime`).

```
public class Plugins {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

    public Plugins(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                   @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                   @JsonProperty("created_at") long createdAt) {
        
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.createdAt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(createdAt)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    }

    // getters, toString(), etc.
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
String json = """
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "someName",
        "created_at": 1665148545
    }""";
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Plugins.class));
```

*Output:*

```
lugins{id='1', name='someName', createdAt=2022-10-07T13:15:45}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to register `JavaTimeModule` module and use required type from `Java-8` time package. Take a look on below example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.Instant;

public class DateApp {
    private final static JsonMapper JSON_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"id\": \"1\",\"name\":\"someName\",\"created_at\": 1665148545}";

        Plugins plugins = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, Plugins.class);
        System.out.println(plugins);
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Plugins {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private Instant createdAt;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Plugins(id=1, name=someName, createdAt=2022-10-07T13:15:45Z)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've upvoted it but not accepted it because adding JavaTimeModule means adding another dependency on the pom, which I would rather avoid as our pom is already ridiculously big as it is!